# CEFSharp v109.1.11 .Net 4.6.2

Tags: gpu, cefsharp

implementing CefSharp 109. Using this version as we have to support some older Win 7 & Win 2008 Server(R2) boxes.

Scenario...
User 1 logs into Win 2008(R2) server and executes our CefSharp enabled app which resides say for sake of argument in "\\machine1\programs\utilies folder". All works as expected.

User 2 logs into same Win 2008(R2) server and executes the same Cef enabled app. The app now says "Stopped Working" and looking at the debug.log there are reports of "ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(985)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=63" which it reports a few times before giving up the ghost with "FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(440)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye."

The applicaiton has an app.manifest and I have tried various command line options like no-sandbox, disable-gpu, disable-gpu-blocklist.

So why working for one user but not another? It is possible that user permissions on user 2 do not allow spawning of CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe which will be on a network share in the same location as our application? If this is a possibility what should I be asking our system guys to be looking at?

I am sure on my Google travels that I saw BrowserSubprocess can be written into you own application removing the need for the external executable? Is this the case and if so can someone point me in the right direction for doing this as whenever I search for any such information Google gives back a long list of sites indicating BrowserSubprocess.exe may be malware, which of course it isn't.

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: Does it work if you run from local disk? Chromium doesn't like being run from a network share. What's different between the two servers? I'd hold off on trying to self host the BrowserSubProcess until you sort out the other issue.

Comment: Hi Amaitland, thanks for getting back to me. There is only one server in play here. User 1 remotes onto server 1 runs our CEF enabled app from Share 1. All is good. User 2 remotes onto server 1 runs our CEF enabled app from Share 1, our app crashes with the gpu-process-host issue. I need to see if company policy will allow me to run directly from server 1. Thanks.

Comment: For testing purposes you can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample (checkout the relevant branch). Make sure you've set a `CachePath` that's unique to each user e.g `AppData`